# MySQL SELECT column COUNT(name) WHERE condition GROUP BY column?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Hey here is the SQL statement I am using

```
$sql = "SELECT number, COUNT(name) FROM people WHERE id='$id' GROUP BY number";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$statarray['stat'.$i] = $row['COUNT(name)'];
$i++; }
```

The number column stores a 0, 1, 2 or a 3 against each name so the array comes back totalling how many names there are against each number.. which works fine.

The only problem is, if all the names have a number 1 stored against them, my array entry 'stat0' does not tell me how many 0s there are because it is replaced by the number of 1s (this is because there are no 0s in the array so the first output is 1s)..

How do I find out how many names have 0s 1s 2s and 3s in their number column including when there are none?.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  numbers.number ,
        COUNT(name)
FROM    ( SELECT    0 AS number
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    3
        ) numbers
        LEFT JOIN people ON people.number = numbers.number AND id='$id' 
GROUP BY numbers.number
```

Or if you have a permanent numbers table as per comments

```
SELECT  numbers.number ,
        COUNT(name)
FROM    numbers
        LEFT JOIN people ON people.number = numbers.number
                            AND id = '$id'
WHERE   numbers.number BETWEEN 0 AND 3
GROUP BY numbers.number
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, Would you be so kind as to explain how this works?.

Comment: You can only select values that exist in your data. This creates an inline derived table with all of the values (a permanent auxiliary numbers table is useful to have and I presume may be more efficient). The left join preserves all values from the left input even if there is no match in the right input.

Comment: Thats great, so if I have an aux/reference table that holds my numbers, then i could join this SELECT to that instead of creating an inline table? How would this change this statement?

Comment: @Wezly - Updated. BTW I noticed an error in my first version. The filter on `id` needs to go in the join condition to avoid making it an inner join.

Comment: Great thank you. At a risk of bombarding this question. If i want to also check another column in the people table.. say 'number2' is it best to do this with a second statement or can i include it in this one?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Probably best to ask this as a new question and provide some example data.